# Techniques to make type hard to indirectly read, but readable if focused on?

Tags: readability

For a print end product: (Not sure if that makes a difference)
Are there any known techniques for distressing type so that once focused upon you can see what it says, but when not focused on, its very hard to 'accidentally' read it?
(Beyond the obvious upside down far away to the edge in a tiny font)

Links, tutorials, or even if this technique/effect has a name would be appreciated.

Comment: You can find good information on this by looking at questions that discuss the opposite, i.e. what makes fonts readable. Some examples are [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/26169/23061) and [this UX post](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/51218/38942)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using position or scaling I'd focus on color, contrast, and the specific font you're using. Using a font with similarly styled letters makes it initially difficult to identify the individual letterforms creating a shape (rather than a word per-say) forcing the reader to focus on tracing and differentiating the letters.